# how to make div appear when hover over another div

Tags: jquery, hover

So for my blogpage. I want to know if it's possible to get the #notepad div appear from the left (scroll from the left side of the screen) whenever I hover over the About Me button. Also, I would like for it to slowly hide back in the left side of the screen.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div>
    <div id="aboutme"><span id="abtext">ABOUT ME</span></div>
<div>


<div id="notepad">
<p>
<ul>
        <li>Guitar Aficionado</li>
        <li>Travel Enthusiast</li>
        <li>Aspiring Entrepreneur</li>
        <li>Fitness Fanatic</li>
        <li>Web Geek</li>
        <li>Avid Writer</li>
        <li>Avid Reader</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#aboutme {position:fixed;
    top:500px;
    left:14px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#494545;
    height:30px;
    width:133px;
    opacity:.5
    }
#aboutme:hover {
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}

#abtext {position:relative;
    top:2px;
    font-family:Broadway;
    font-size:22px;
    padding-left:3px;
    color:white;
    }

#notepad{background:url(http://s25.postimg.org/gmjef3c6m/lined_paper_by_LL_stock.jpg                             );
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius:10px;
        position:relative;
        height:380px;
        width:380px;
           }

ul {
font-family:Comic Sans MS;
font-size:28px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Which div would you like to add the `on("hover")` to?

Comment: the #aboutme Button. So when ever I hover over it, the big notepad will appear from the left of the screen. i can't seem to find the proper coding for it

Comment: i would also like to note that there is another button on top of my #aboutme button and another one below it. I would like for the notepad to appear from the left of the screen without bumping in to these buttons.

Comment: what div tag you are ending in ur html? chk 1st tag after body. it shouldn't be there, more like <div> instead of </div>

Comment: good eye! thank you. but still no prevail =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)  and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) into JQuery

```
$("#aboutme").mouseover(function() {
  $("#notepad").show();
});
```

Comment: care to show me a fiddle. i am new to web design and jQuery is still a little confusing to me.

Comment: you just  need to load JQuery file , 
Put <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
into <head> tag
Before using my code

Comment: i tried it but it didn't do anything. Maybe my jQuery coding is incorrect. Again, the coding pattern for jQuery is still confusing to me. $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aboutme").mouseover(function() {
  $("#notepad").show();
});

Comment: i added this coding on my script.js file. but it didn't do anything. =( sorry

$("#aboutme").mouseover(function() {
  $("#notepad").show('slow');
});

Comment: good to know. jquery is very very easy, most of time you just copy paste sample code and change the class or id for selector. always check documentation of it. it have easy to understand examples

Comment: so now my only problem is that when it appears, some div's are over the notepad. is there any way to make the notepad float over other divs?